# Pulling a value from one CSV based on a value in another

Tags: ruby, fastercsv

I am trying to figure out the best way to pull a value from a CSV file called `lookup.csv` based on a value in `master.csv`, and then save the new file as `output.csv`.

In the example below, the master file has three columns of data with the last column being `City`. I'd like to replace the `City` name with the `City Code` from the `lookup.csv` file.

I don't have a DB that I can lookup from so I am having to use the CSV file. I am trying to use FasterCSV with Ruby 1.8.7.

Example File Structure:

master.csv:

```
First Name | Last Name | City
Joey       | Jello     | Atlanta
Home       | Boy       | Dallas
```

lookup.csv:

```
City    | City ID
Atlanta | 12345
Dallas  | 12346
Houston | 12347
```

output.csv:

```
First Name | Last Name | City
Joey       | Jello     | 12345
Home       | Boy       | 12346
```

Comment: "I don't have a DB" Why not look into SQLite? It's available for almost all OSes out there and great for temporary and in-memory databases. That'd simplify and speed up your task. Load the CSV into it, then you can do random accesses instead of sequential file reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using 1.9, where `FasterCSV` is available as `CSV` in the standard lib. First I'd create a lookup hash out of `lookup.csv`:

```
cities = Hash[CSV.read('lookup.csv', :col_sep => ' | ').to_a[1..-1]]
```

If the file is very big, you might want to iterate over it with `CSV.foreach` and build the hash row by row:

```
cities = {}
CSV.foreach('lookup.csv', :col_sep => ' | ', :headers => true, :return_headers => false) do |line|
  cities[line['City']] = line['City ID']  
end
```

Then iterate over `master.csv`, do a lookup of the city in the hash and write that to `output.csv`:

```
CSV.open('output.csv', "w", :headers => ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'City ID'], :write_headers => true) do |output|
  CSV.foreach('master.csv', :col_sep => ' | ', :headers => true, :return_headers => false) do |line|
    output << [line['First Name'], line['Last Name'], cities[line['City']]]
  end  
end
```

Comment: Michael - Thank you very much for the example. This worked exactly as I needed.

Comment: Glad to help! If you want to throw in an upvote with accepting the answer I'd finally have my 20k reputation ;-)