# How do I pull data from multiple CSV files without multiple loops?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have two CSV files: "users" and "enrollments":

001.csv:

```
user_id,user_name,state
12345,test_account,active
```

002.csv:

```
course_id,user_id,state
67890,12345,active
```

I need to create one file like active_enrollments.csv:

```
course_id,user_name
67890,test_account
```

Without looping through the files multiple times, how can I parse these to generate the file active_enrollments.csv?

Here is what I have so far, but I am getting a lot of duplicates:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open("active-enrollments.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["course_id", "user_name", "user_id","course_name", "status"]
end
Dir["csvs/*.csv"].each do |file|
  #puts file
CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
if row['user_id'] && row ['course_id'] #finds enrollment csvs
  if row['state'] == "active" #checks for active enrollments
    state = row['state']
    course_id = row['course_id']
    user_id = row['user_id']
    Dir["csvs/*.csv"].each do |files|
      CSV.foreach(files, :headers => true) do |user|
        if user['user_name']
          if user_id == user['user_id']
            user_name = user['user_name']
            Dir["csvs/*.csv"].each do |file|
              CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |courses|
                if course_id == courses['course_id']
                  course_name = courses['course_name']
                  CSV.open("active-enrollments.csv", "a") do |csv|
                    csv << [course_id, user_name, user_id, course_name, state]
                  end
                end 
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
end
end
```

I know this is simple, but I can't seem to get it without looping through the files multiple times and generating lots of duplicates.

Comment: found it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127948/pulling-a-value-from-one-csv-based-on-a-value-in-another?rq=1

Comment: This is a great use for a database. I'd recommend looking into [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) as a database, and [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html) as an interface/ORM to SQLite. Look through the first couple documents for Sequel to see how easily it lets you set up a trivial database for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

In lieu of using a database or a bunch of full-fledged models, I would suggest using a simple Hash as a lookup.

The following has not been tested and I left out all filters.

Separate the user from the enrollment csvs by name and iterate once over the user csvs to create a lookup by `user_id`.

```
users_csvs = Dir['csvs/users-*.csv']
enrollment_csvs = Dir['csvs/enrollment-*.csv']

users = {} 
users_csvs.each do |user_file|
  CSV.foreach(user_file, :headers => true) do |row|
    # Put in whatever data you will need later
    users[row['user_id']] = {:user_name => row['user_name'], :state => row['state']}
  end
end

consolidated_csv = []
enrollment_csvs.each do |enrollment_file|
  CSV.foreach(enrollment_file, :headers => true) do |row|
    user_id = row['user_id']
    if user = users[user_id]
      # Put in whatever you want from the two objects
      consolidated_csv << {:course_id => row['course_id'], :user_name => row['user_name']}
    end
  end
end

CSV.open("active-enrollments.csv", "wb") do |csv|
   csv << ['course_id', 'user_name']
   consolidated_csv.each { |row| csv << [row[:course_id], row[:user_name]] }
end
```

Comment: While it's a start, this would break down quickly on large CSV files in the GB range. The OP doesn't give us a hint about the size of the files currently used, or how big they could grow, but it's not very scalable because it's holding everything in RAM.

Comment: @theTinMan you are absolutely correct.  There are plenty of more complicated strategies like fetching n rows at a time, serializing the lookup hash as json perhaps, etc

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to use Sqlite, pull the data from the CSV files, stick it in a temporary database, then query the db to generate the final output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code showing how to do this using a simple SQLite database and the Sequel ORM:

```
require 'csv'
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/temp.db')

# user_id,user_name,state
# 12345,test_account,active
DB.create_table :csv1 do
  primary_key :id
  Integer :user_id
  String :user_name
  String :state
end

TABLE_001 = DB[:csv1]
CSV.foreach('001.csv', :headers => :first_row) do |row|
  TABLE_001.insert(
    :user_id   => row['user_id'],
    :user_name => row['user_name'],
    :state     => row['state']
  )
end

# course_id,user_id,state
# 67890,12345,active
DB.create_table :csv2 do
  primary_key :id
  Integer :course_id
  Integer :user_id
  String :state
end

# I need to create one file like active_enrollments.csv:
#
#     course_id,user_name
#     67890,test_account
TABLE_002 = DB[:csv2]
CSV.foreach('002.csv', :headers => :first_row) do |row|
  TABLE_002.insert(
    :course_id => row['course_id'],
    :user_id   => row['user_id'],
    :state     => row['state']
  )
end

CSV.open('active_enrollments.csv', 'w') do |csv_out|
  TABLE_001.each do |row_001|
    row_002 = TABLE_002.where(:user_id => row_001[:user_id]).first
    csv_out << [row_002[:course_id], row_001[:user_name]]
  end
end
```

After running, "active_enrollments.csv" contains:

```
67890,test_account
```

This is a very scalable solution.

Running this twice will get an error because Sequel will try to generate new tables in the database. Erase the file, or add exception handlers for both `create_table` blocks.